# Is it possible to execute a MATLAB program without MATLAB software?

Tags: matlab

I've a MATLAB program without the software. How can I execute the program

Answer (score 4):

Try GNU Octave, it say's "it strives for exact compatibility, so many of your projects developed for MATLAB may run in Octave"
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

To install it, open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install octave
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install octave` maybe used to install from the official Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Do you have to use apt-get, I thought it had changed to just apt install? I know its a minor point as I think both will work, I just wondered if there was any benefit from typing the full command?

Comment: My main idea that Octave is in repositories. `sudo apt install octave` is ok too.